# How to declare a variable to host multiple values

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a function which takes random number of any value as parameter:

```
func myFunc(values: Any...) {
     ...   
}
```

I know I can call this function like:

```
myFunc(1, "name", true)
```

But my question is, how can I declare one variable host all the comma-separated values & pass that variable to this function as a parameter?

I mean something like: `myFunc(myValues)`

How to declare `myValues`?

**========== UPDATE ==========**

I tried with array `[Any]` as the parameter variable:

```
let parameters:[Any] = [1, "name", true]
```

then, pass to function:

```
myFunc(values: parameters)
```

But in `myFunc` when I iterate over the parameters, I got the full array during the 1st iteration:

```
func myFunc(values: Any...) {
  values.forEach { (val) in
     print(val) // it has only one iteration, val = [1, "name", true]
  }
}
```

Why? I would like `myFunc` could iterate over each element in array.

Comment: You can pass function params an array of ID, if your value is all objects type.

Comment: The value is not all object type. That's why I use `Any` not `AnyObject` as parameter type.

Comment: then just make it an array using myValues:[Any]

Comment: It doesn't work, please see my update.